# Another problem-specific design question

Tags: design-patterns, class-design

Say I have a Ninja with certain configurable skills.  By configurable, I mean the program reads in a configuration file and adds them in at runtime.  ie:

```
Ninja:
  color: Red
  Skills:
    - High Jump
    - Invisibility
```

Now, assume these skills need to dynamically add functionality to the Ninja class.  As in, if we configure Ninja to have a High Jump skill, then the class needs to follow the CanHighJump Interface, with public void highJump() as a method.

Now there are two ways I can think of going about this.  My first reaction would be to have a Ninja class with String color and then use Reflection to add in the functionality.  However, now I realize I could do it through a relational database as well.  Have a Ninja class with String color, and forget about any objects relating Ninjas with Skills - instead, whenever I need to check for a skill, just make a call to the database retrieving the possible skills that class can use.  Those are the only two truly dynamic solutions I can come up with, and I can't comprehend the design pros/cons of each.  I have a feeling the database solution would be far more scale-able, but the reflection method would make most sense to me when coding.  No need to query which skills a Ninja has, because I could easily check for the interface.

I'm hoping someone can give me a bit of insight over a standard design solution for this problem.  Whether it be one of the two I came up with, or more likely something i didn't think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like what you're looking for is close to the [Capability Pattern](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/timboudreau/archive/2008/08/the_capability.html).

```
public interface IHasSkills {
    public <T> getSkill(Class<T> skill);
}

public interface ICanAddSkills extends IHasSkills {
    public void addSkill(ISkill skill)
}

public class Ninja implements ICanAddSkills {
    private List<ISkill> _skills;

    public void addSkill(ISkill skill) {
        _skills.Add(skill);
    }

    public <T> GetSkill(Class<T> skillType) {
        for(ISkill skill : _skills) {
           if(skill instanceof skillType) return skill;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public interface ISkill{}

public interface IHighjumpSkill extends IHighJumpCapable{
    public void highJump();
}

public class NinjaHighJumpSkill implements IHighJumpCapable{
    private Ninja _canHighJump;
    public NinjaHighJumpSkill(Ninja ninja) {
        _canHighJump = ninja;
    }

    @Override
    public void highJump() {
        //Note that this could be combined with the [Property Pattern][2] 
        //(which was referenced in another answer) to set/get arbitrary
        //properties on the ninja.
        _canHighJump.DoWhateverAHighJumpDoes();
    }
}
```

You can use this pattern to add new capabilities to an object without having to actually implement them in the object.  The client will get an instance of `IHighJumpCapable` when they call `myNinja.getSkill(IHighJumpCapable.class)` if the ninja has this skill, or null otherwise.  You can then call the highJump() method on the IHighJumpCapable.

```
public static void Main(String args[]) {
    Ninja ninja = new Ninja();
    ninja.AddSkill(new NinjaHighJumpSkill(ninja));
    IHighJumpCapable canHighJump = ninja.GetSkill(IHighJumpCapable.class);
    canHighJump.highJump();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be what the property pattern was getting at, just a bit more specific to the problem.  Thanks for taking the time to write the code.  I will end up doing this.  I've never thought of the HasSkills -> CanAddSkills relationship before.  That's very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sort of extension to what Ryan has suggested. The following way will make a ninja perform the skill without necessarily asking and checking the skill type  if this is desired.

See if this adds value -

```
public class Ninja implements ICanAddSkills {
private List<ISkill> _skills;

public void addSkill(ISkill skill) {
    _skills.Add(skill);
}

public <T> getSkill(Class<T> skillType) {
    for(ISkill skill : _skills) {
       if(skill instanceof skillType) return skill;
    }
    return null;
    }
}

    public interface ISkill{
        public void performSkill();
    }

public interface IHighjumpSkill extends ISkill,IHighJumpCapable{
    public void highJump();
}

public class NinjaHighJumpSkill implements IHighjumpSkill{
    private Ninja _canHighJump;
    public NinjaHighJumpSkill(Ninja ninja) {
        _canHighJump = ninja;
    }

    @Override
    public void highJump() {
        _canHighJump.DoWhateverAHighJumpDoes();
    }

    // delgate to whatever this skill can do
    @Override
    public void performSkill() {
        highJump();
    }
}


public static void Main(String args[]) {
    Ninja ninja = new Ninja();
    ninja.AddSkill(new NinjaHighJumpSkill(ninja));
    // loop through skills and perform actions using performSkill()

     for(ISkill skill : _skills) {
          skill.performSkill();
        }

}
```